# Dynamic loading of script shows different behaviour for same JS file

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

While loading a JS SDK on our website I was trying out few different ways.
I noticed that Snippet 1 causes CORS error, while Snippet 2 loads the **same script** on **same page** without any issues.

**Snippet 1** (Using document.body.appendChild, throws CORS exception)

```
 const url = 'https://www.example.com/sdk.js';
 const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
 scriptTag.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
 scriptTag.setAttribute('src', url);
 document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

**Snippet 2** (Using parentNode.insertBefore, no CORS exception)

```
 const element = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');

 scriptTag.async = !0;
 scriptTag.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
 scriptTag.src = 'https://www.example.com/sdk.js';
 element.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptTag, element);
```

I tried to find why the behaviour is different for each case, but could not find any reason for it.

Can someone point out to me why I see this behaviour?

Comment: I think the element property name is "crossOrigin", not "crossorigin".

Comment: You are right, just tested with scriptTag.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'  and now I get the same behaviour. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I see running your code is the on pointed by @Pointy on the comment, the first script generates:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://www.example.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

the second one:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.example.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

running on my console, so probably the `crossorigin` is responsable for the cors error. (the same happened on console, btw)